# Lock a particular browser tab with a password (in Firefox or Chrome)

Tags: web-browser, security

I have been trying to find an extension or plugin to block unauthorized access to a browser tab i.e. each time a person clicks on the browser, he should enter the password. But I have not been able to find one yet.

I am open to a solution on Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: Do you also require that the tab not show the title of the page? It might get confusing for you if you have several, but could save you from having to explain why you have locked a dating site/porn hub/vote for Trump page or something equally emvbbarasssing

Comment: No the tab name appearing is fine. Sometimes we will have to share a remote instance of a system and i dont want others to see what i have opened, so just wondering if there is any option for this

Comment: But won#t they know what you have opened by reading the tab titles?

Comment: No I dont have that problem. My requirement is to protect the content , it is fine if they see the title . For ex: Its ok for them to know i have stack over flow opened  but I dont want them to snoop around my account by opening and going through content in the tab.

Comment: I'm curious why a browser-specific lock is wanted - why don't you simply lock the entire computer? That way, 'they' can't see anything.

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome "Tabs Protection Password" extension will satisfy your needs. It requires to enter an initial e-mail/password and it protects all opened tabs and also prevents the creation of new ones by requiring for your password.

It also hides all opened tabs so they are not visible by their titles.

- That does not guarantee that an advanced user will not disable the extension through Google Chrome settings
- You have to also enable it for Incognito mode (through Chrome settings) in order to work for this mode as well.

*Despite the title, by reading "each time a person clicks on the browser", I understand that you need it globally for all tabs.*